# How to get logged in user's uid from session in Django?

Tags: django

I have implemented a registration/login/authentication system using [this Django guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/).

But, how would I access a user's information from my views so I can send the user's information to a template file?

I want to be able to access a user's ID so I can submit a form with the user's ID attached to the form.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a [`django.contrib.auth.models.User`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#users) object attached to the request; you can access it in a view via `request.user`. You must have the [auth middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests) installed, though.

Answer (score 79):

In case anyone wants to actually extract a user ID from an actual Session object (for whatever reason - I did!), here's how:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

session_key = '8cae76c505f15432b48c8292a7dd0e54'

session = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
session_data = session.get_decoded()
print session_data
uid = session_data.get('_auth_user_id')
user = User.objects.get(id=uid)
```

Credit should go to [Scott Barnham](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/12/04/get-user-from-session-key-in-django/)

Comment: Cool, this could save up 1 query: `request.session.get('_auth_user_id')`, instead of `request.user.id`, but it seems that `RequestMiddleware` or `RequestContext` actually do make a query to retrieve the auth user, so this is not actual saving in some cases.

Comment: when does `_auth_user_id` gets attached to the `Session` object while creating a new `Session`?

Comment: @VikasGoyal No, when the user logs in. See django.contrib.auth.login()

Answer (score 8):

This:

```
def view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
         user = request.user
         print(user)
         # do something with user
```

Answer (score 2):

An even easier way to do this is to install [django-extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and run the management command print_user_for_session.

And this is how they do it:

https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/management/commands/print_user_for_session.py

Answer (score 0):

In case hwjp solution doesn't work for you ("Data is corrupted"), here is another solution:

```
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
import json

def session_utoken(msg, secret_key, class_name='SessionStore'):
    key_salt = "django.contrib.sessions" + class_name
    sha1 = hashlib.sha1((key_salt + secret_key).encode('utf-8')).digest()
    utoken = hmac.new(sha1, msg=msg, digestmod=hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()
    return utoken


def decode(session_data, secret_key, class_name='SessionStore'):
    encoded_data = base64.b64decode(session_data)
    utoken, pickled = encoded_data.split(b':', 1)
    expected_utoken = session_utoken(pickled, secret_key, class_name)
    if utoken.decode() != expected_utoken:
        raise BaseException('Session data corrupted "%s" != "%s"',
                            utoken.decode(),
                            expected_utoken)
    return json.loads(pickled.decode('utf-8'))

s = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
decode(s.session_data, 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY'))
```

credit to: http://joelinoff.com/blog/?p=920

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from importlib import import_module
from  django.contrib.auth.middleware import get_user
from django.http import HttpRequest


engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
SessionStore = engine.SessionStore
session = SessionStore(sessionid)
request = HttpRequest()
request.session = session
user = get_user(request)
```