# get the currently logged user request.user in utils.py

Tags: python, django

I need to get the currently logged user 'budget_id' (column from database) in utils.py. Normally in views.py I use:

```
def login_user(request):
    return request.user.last_name
```

utils.py fragment:

```
class Calendar(HTMLCalendar):
def __init__(self, year=None, month=None,):
    self.year = year
    self.month = month
    super(Calendar, self).__init__()


def formatday(self, day, events):
    budget_id = request.user.budget_id // need here
```

Comment: Pass the request as a parameter of the `formatday` function

Comment: A. you restructure your codebase so that you can pass the `request` from the view all the way down to whatever utils you might need it in. B. You write a middleware that makes the request somehow globally available, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633952/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-context-from-everywhere-in-django

Comment: You can also use Django sessions to get the user id, see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000040/how-to-get-logged-in-users-uid-from-session-in-django